# Query to get the rank of a user in a database table based on two rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on an app where users can take online exams and then they need to know their rank on all exams taken in the app.

This is the database table structure:
[image]

After taking the exam, I need to get the rank for the specific user (usuario) based on two rows, first row to get the rank must be the bigger (puntuacion) and in case of same (puntuacion) the second row to be taken into account is the smaller (duracion) for an specific exam subject (materia).

I need your help to create the needed query.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more deeply and you can also create dummy sql table and your query at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3):

You want the results sorted by "puntuacion" and "duracion". That's done with `order by`

`SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY puntuacion DESC, duracion ASC`

It's not quite clear how you want to sort it, so you may have to switch around `ASC` with `DESC`.

If you want to add the row number and have a high enough MariaDB/Mysql-Version (Mysql 8.0) then you can use a window-function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

`SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY puntuacion DESC, duracion ASC) as row,
*
FROM your_table
ORDER BY puntuacion DESC, duracion ASC`

Comment: I have got a working query, Please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the users are unique (delete DESC if you need to rank by ascending order) :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY puntuacion DESC, duracion DESC;
```

Fetch it as an array and get the row with `$result[array_search($user)]`. Not tested but it should work, let me know.

This is kinda heavy if you have a lot of users (it loads every users every time), but I don't see other solutions.

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is to get the rank for an specific user and for an specific materia. Not the order inside the table

Comment: It is ordered by puntuacion and then by duracion, so it is ranked

Comment: I know, but how to get the position inside the ordered results?

Comment: By the key. But the solution of Markus is even better, it does not load all the users, go for his solution, definitly. It's quite the same but he gets the row number before fetching

Comment: I have got a working query, Please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have got a working query:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM tb_examenes t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE materia = 10 ORDER by puntuacion DESC, duracion ASC
```

Then I only have to filter for the field I need.